# Cannot input text into a React search bar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, jsx

Update - solved, Thanks Konrad! I had text that was blocking the search bar, adding pointer-events: none; to the text fixed my issue.

I am learning react and trying to create a search bar. Right now, I just want to have the user's input to the search bar be logged to the console or pop up in a message when they submit text.
However, I cannot even enter text into my search bar right now.

I have tried looking at the react documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and I think the issue has something to do with setting state but I am not sure where I am going wrong. I saw other people on stack overflow had this issue, but it was fixed for them when they added 'value=' to their <in bar which did not work for me.

Thank you for reading!

```
import React from 'react'
import './SearchBar.css'

class SearchBar extends React.Component { //
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A value was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className='Container'>
          <form className='SearchBar' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Enter the link to your IMDB profile' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </form>
        <p className='Warning'>Make sure your imdb profile is set to public!</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default SearchBar
```

As pointed out by Konrad below, the isolated component works fine, so there must be some issue in my integration. When I comment out my App.css file, it also works fine, so it is some issue in those that is causing me an issue, does anyone know what I need to add?
Here is my app.css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    height: 20vmin;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(20px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.Wrapped{
  position:absolute;
  left: 40%; 
  height: 75%;
  font-size: 75px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-family: "Apple Chancery", cursive;
  color:deeppink
}


.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

and my app.js:

```
import logo from './Logo_2016.png';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1 className='Wrapped'> Wrapped </h1>
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p> Welcome! </p>
        <SearchBar/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sanderson-oceuob?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you @Konrad! I have pinned down the issue to my app.css file which I have copied above - but I do not know the issue is. I also did not know css sheets could affect functionality...

Comment: Your `Wrapped` text obscures the text box. You can add `pointer-events: none;` so it won't be clickable